# wsg 1984 - calc distance between 2 geo points

Tags: dictionary, geolocation

i need a peace of code in C# that can calc the distance between 2 points in a map that has a wsg1984 format

Comment: I'd hate to see this closed, if only to see the math involved, but could please atleast clean up the question, perhaps include a link to what WSG 84 actually is, and some example data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Haversine forumla, or the spherical law of cosines.
See http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html for formulas.
Should be simple to translate to C#

Answer (score 0):

transform to metric system 3395, and calculate distance using known formula
distance = sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)

It is not exact, but it suits for 99% cases.